# why @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) also apply for screen width less than 768px

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, blogger

The css for min-width 768 is not working properly in mobile. But same css is working properly in inpect mode for width less than 768 in chrome desktop browser.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
#main {
    max-width: 75%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

But when I switch to mobile mode in inspect tool it's again not working properly.

[image]

I am trying to edit the blogger classic theme.
link of the blog https://egadgetdeals.blogspot.com/2019/11/what-youll-build-in-part-1.html?m=1

Comment: If you click off that element then click on it again, does it still show that css? I think your view is caching like if you have that element clicked on then put it in device view, it will show you old styles else that shouldn't be possible. You can try to recreate that in a http://jsfiddle.net if you think this is actually an issue

Comment: Does it sort itself if you were to refresh? Or even close inspector and reopen? I've found the emulator in Dev tools to have some inconsistencies until I close and reopen inspector after selecting a mobile emulator or new viewport size

Comment: Just refresh page and see if you see the same thing

Comment: I tried everything but it's still not working

Comment: check the link https://egadgetdeals.blogspot.com/2019/11/what-youll-build-in-part-1.html?m=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meta tag viewport to avoid zoom is missing, add this into the head tag :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: You can find more details about it on this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag